# jquery.backgroundSize.js not workingie8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, pie-chart

I'm using [jquery.backgroundSize.js](http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/) plugin, but I can't make it work in IE8.

I downloaded from the official site, then I play the demo and nothing happened. I've made a test page and it worked well IE9, Firefox etc but nothing in IE8.

**css:**

```
#main{
    background:url('parthenon.jpg') no-repeat; 
    margin:20px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="main">
    background
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#main").css({backgroundSize: "contain"});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not support CSS `background-size`.

The page you linked is a jQuery hack try to implement it in older browsers; if it isn't working for you, then the implication is that you're not loading the plugin properly.

You could also consider using an alternative option: The [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) library implements support for CSS `background-size` into old IE versions, and with CSS3Pie you can put it directly into your CSS code, as you would normally for other browsers.

Comment: I'm sure the the plugin is properly loaded, in other browsers I cant see that it adds the property background-size:contain to the element. I'll try the CSS3 PIE.

Comment: Background-size it's not supported by css3pie, other fix please!

Comment: @novoa: It is supported, but note that you need css3pie v2 for `background-size`. (sorry I forgot to point that out earlier)

Comment: I downloaded the V2, same result my friend. I tested the border-radius for ie8 and it's working but not the background-size.
My css looks like this now :  
#main{
 background:url('parthenon.jpg') no-repeat;  
 background-size:cover;
 margin:20px;
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 behavior: url(PIE/PIE.htc);
}

Comment: try `-pie-background: url('parthenon.jpg') no-repeat contain;`

Comment: try `-pie-background: url('parthenon.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50% / contain;` ?

Comment: It works now, for some reason it didn't 2 hours ago, anyway, THANK YOU !